# Bootstrap glyphicons behaving strange in codeigniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

So I'm using CI for the first time, along with bootstrap. Weird thing is happening with the glyphicons on my pages.

If I start my url in the browser with "`www.`", it all works fine. If I don't use it (so example.com instead of www.example.com), the glyphicons do not show. In their place are empty square boxes.

Can someone explain to me why it is behaving like this?

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.[mysitehere].ovh/';
```

Note: If I change the above to '`http://[mysitehere].ovh`' then the reverse is true. If the `www.` at the beginning is present, then the glyphicons don't work and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see how is that related to icons, but better solution is to add in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

CodeIgniter is able to figure out the base URL by itself.